# Change from 'extends Components' to 'createReactClass'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have implemented the following timer in react, which uses the old way of implementing by 'extends Component'. I am still struggling with how to implement this by using 'createReactClass'. How should it be adapted?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Timer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 1
    }
  }

  render () {
    const {count} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Current Count: {count}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
  // setInterval
  // clearInterval
  componentDidMount () {
    const {startCount} = this.props
    this.setState({
      count: startCount
    })
    this.doIntervalChange()
  }

  doIntervalChange = () => {
      this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count - 1
      }))
    }, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearInterval(this.myInterval)
  }
}

export default Timer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should do that. createReactClass is not the new way to declare a class component.

Comment: Do you mean a functional component that uses hooks etc?

Comment: yeah, that is the *really* old way to create a component. Maybe you mean creating a functional components using hooks?

Comment: If you must use `createReactClass` for some reason (don't want to be transpiling ES6 anymore, but still can transpile JSX?) then https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html gives you a good indication on how to do it. However as others suggested you really should not do this